# Python - Pandas - Organize in columns poorly structured csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a huge csv file with information that should be in columns, all thrown together in a row, in any order. I know how to split the columns using separators, but when I do that, single columns do not contain consistent information. The example is this:

```
Person  Information
Mary    Married: Yes
John    Number of children: three, Married: No
Susan
Betty   Do you like icecream?: Yes, Married: Yes, Number of chidren: four
Daniel  Do you like icecream?: Sometimes, Number of chidren: two
Conrad  Married: No, Do you like icecream?: No
Ofelia  Married: No, Do you read?: Yes, Do you like icecream?: Some flavors
```

When I split into columns using str.split, I end up with a column containing:

```
Yes
three
(empty space)
Yes (but this is the answer to another question)
Sometimes
```

etc. What I want is a column containing all the information if the person is married, another column containing the number of children, another if they like icecream, etc.

Comment: what should your output look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read file line by line by processing its lines. I tried to recreate the example you gave us and with the following code snippet you can parse your string with multiple, unordered keys:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()

#Example recreation
str = "Number of children: three, Married: No"
str1 = "Do you like icecream?: Yes, Married: Yes, Number of chidren: four"
str2 = "Married: No, Do you read?: Yes, Do you like icecream?: Some flavors"

strings = list([str1, str2, str])

for s in strings:
    Dict = dict((x.strip(), y.strip()) for x, y in (element.split(':') for element in s.split(', ')))
    result = result.append(Dict, ignore_index=True)
```

It will give you the following results:

```
  Do you like icecream? Married Number of chidren Do you read? Number of children
0                   Yes     Yes              four          NaN                NaN
1          Some flavors      No               NaN          Yes                NaN
2                   NaN      No               NaN          NaN              three
```

As you can see, there is a spelling mistake in your example in the word "children".

Answer (score 0):

Making a lot of assumptions about the format of your data. But if the pattern of your data is `NAME COLUMN_NAME: COLUMN_DATA, COLUMN_NAME: COLUMN_DATA` you need to `str.split()` to grab the name, `str.split(', ')` to grab the other fields, and `str.split(': ')` to grab each column name and column value.

```py
# read the csv lines
records = []


def process_text(text):
    """
    text format: "NAME COLUMN_NAME: COLUMN_DATA, COLUMN_NAME: COLUMN_DATA"
    """
    # separate NAME from other columns
    data = text.split()
    # create a dict for all the COLUMN_NAME: COLUMN_DATA values
    fields = {
        field[0]: field[1] for field in [field.split(': ') for field in ' '.join(data[1:]).split(', ')]
    }
    # add the NAME to the dict
    fields['name']: data[0]

    return fields

# process line by line and make a dataframe
pd.DataFrame([process_text(record) for record in records])
```